# How to delete previously indexed documents in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two documents indexed like below
Document 1

```
{
  "_index": "custom-design",
  "_type": "cars",
  "_id": "porche129",
  "_score": 1.2413527,
  "_source": {
    "clientID": "ps1233443",
    "customisation": "yes",
    "userType": "heavy",
    "totalBilling": 3000
  }
}
```

}

Document 2

```
{
  "_index": "custom-design",
  "_type": "cars",
  "_id": "porche232",
  "_score": 1.2413527,
  "_source": {
    "clientID": "ps1233443",
    "customisation": "yes",
    "userType": "heavy",
    "totalBilling": 3000
  }
}
}
```

As you can see both documents are indexed and have different ids, but the same content.Is it possible to detect and eliminate the duplicate documents after they are indexed?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to crate hash per document. 
But then as that is not possible now , lets resort to scripts to do that.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/Index/IndexType/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": "terms": {
      "script": "doc['clientID'].value + doc['customisation'].value+doc['userType'].value+doc['totalBilling'].value",
      "min_doc_count": 2
    },      
    "aggs": {
      "duplicateDocuments": {
        "top_hits": {}
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

If you look at the results , you can see duplicate documents here.
Now find the duplicate ID and do a bulk delete.

You can read more on these approaches here - https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch